# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset - json data

Tags: php, json

I get the error

> Warning: Illegal string offset '@name' in ...

but only in 22 row based on this particular example.

I looked for a solution, that this might be from taking a string as an array, but I don't get a clue how to deal with this. Here is the code:

```
$setlista="23e278a7";  

$url = "http://api.setlist.fm/rest/0.1/setlist/".$setlista.".json";

  $json = file_get_contents($url);
  $obj = json_decode($json, true);

  $setlistByEvent = $obj['setlist']['sets']['set'];

  $countSongs = 1;

  for ($i = 0; $i <= count($setlistByEvent) - 1; $i++) {

  echo "<ul>";

  if($i > 0) {
    echo "Encore " . $setlistByEvent[$i]['@encore'] ;
  }

  foreach($setlistByEvent[$i]['song'] as $row) {
      echo "<li>";
      echo $countSongs . ". ";
      echo $row['@name'];
      echo "</li>";
    $countSongs++;
  }

  echo "</ul>"; 

  }
```

The output is:

> 1. This House Is Not for Sale
> 2. Raise Your Hands
> 3. Knockout
> 4. You Give Love a Bad Name
> 5. Born to Be My Baby
> 6. Lost Highway
> 7. We Weren't Born to Follow
> 8. Lay Your Hands On Me
> 9. In These Arms
> 10. New Year's Day
> 11. (You Want to) Make a Memory
> 12. Bed of Roses
> 13. It's My Life
> 14. Someday I'll Be Saturday Night
> 15. Wanted Dead or Alive
> 16. I'll Sleep When I'm Dead
> 17. Have a Nice Day
> 18. Keep the Faith
> 19. Bad Medicine
>       Encore 1
> 20. Always
> 21. Livin' on a Prayer 
>       Encore 2
> 22. Warning: Illegal string offset '@name' in...

Comment: Then remove the @

Comment: Removing @ in @name makes it not showing names at all, and the error is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Fiddle Demo](https://eval.in/875810)

> I looked for a solution, that this might be from taking a string as an
> array, but I don't get a clue how to deal with this. Here is the code:
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset '@name' in ...

**Cause :**

You got error because api response was not array for last one, for remaining all  it was `"song":[]`

```
            {
               "@encore":"2",
               "song":{
                  "@name":"These Days"
               }
            }
```

So for last set `$row = "These Days"`

**Here is difference which you can make out easily**

```
(
    [@encore] => 1
    [song] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [@name] => Always
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [@name] => Livin' on a Prayer
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [@encore] => 2
    [song] => Array
        (
            [@name] => These Days
        )

)
```

**Same in json**

[image]

**So you can check before whether its array like below**

```
foreach($setlistByEvent[$i]['song'] as $row) {
      if(is_array($row) && isset($row['@name']))
      {

      }
}
```

Below one may help you, which gives all song names in array,

```
<?php

$setlista="23e278a7";  
$url = "http://api.setlist.fm/rest/0.1/setlist/".$setlista.".json";
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);

$songs = array();
foreach($arr['setlist']['sets']['set'] as $list){

    // if you want filter by @encore for example, then uncomment below line
    // if($list['@encore']==1)

    // this is where we got issue, lets make array
    if(!isset($list['song'][0])){ $list['song']=array($list['song']); }

    $songs = array_merge($songs, array_column($list['song'],'@name'));
}
print_r($songs);

// Now you got array of songnames, you may use loop now

?>
```

**Output:**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [0] => This House Is Not for Sale
    [1] => Raise Your Hands
    [2] => Knockout
    [3] => You Give Love a Bad Name
    [4] => Born to Be My Baby
    [5] => Lost Highway
    [6] => We Weren't Born to Follow
    [7] => Lay Your Hands On Me
    [8] => In These Arms
    [9] => New Year's Day
    [10] => (You Want to) Make a Memory
    [11] => Bed of Roses
    [12] => It's My Life
    [13] => Someday I'll Be Saturday Night
    [14] => Wanted Dead or Alive
    [15] => I'll Sleep When I'm Dead
    [16] => Have a Nice Day
    [17] => Keep the Faith
    [18] => Bad Medicine
    [19] => Always
    [20] => Livin' on a Prayer
    [21] => These Days
)
```

Json response, from api

```
{
   "setlist":{
      "@id":"23e278a7",
      "@versionId":"7343f625",
      "@tour":"This House Is Not for Sale",
      "@eventDate":"23-09-2017",
      "@lastUpdated":"2017-09-24T16:26:18.000+0000",
      "artist":{
         "@mbid":"5dcdb5eb-cb72-4e6e-9e63-b7bace604965",
         "@tmid":"734608",
         "@name":"Bon Jovi",
         "@sortName":"Bon Jovi",
         "@disambiguation":"group",
         "url":"https://www.setlist.fm/setlists/bon-jovi-33d6b851.html"
      },
      "venue":{
         "@id":"6bd41616",
         "@name":"Allianz Parque",
         "city":{
            "@id":"6324358",
            "@name":"São Paulo",
            "@state":"São Paulo",
            "@stateCode":"27",
            "coords":{
               "@lat":"-23.6270250218409",
               "@long":"-46.6350328065523"
            },
            "country":{
               "@code":"BR",
               "@name":"Brazil"
            }
         },
         "url":"https://www.setlist.fm/venue/allianz-parque-sao-paulo-brazil-6bd41616.html"
      },
      "sets":{
         "set":[
            {
               "song":[
                  {
                     "@name":"This House Is Not for Sale"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Raise Your Hands"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Knockout"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"You Give Love a Bad Name"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Born to Be My Baby"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Lost Highway"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"We Weren't Born to Follow"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Lay Your Hands On Me"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"In These Arms"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"New Year's Day"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"(You Want to) Make a Memory"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Bed of Roses"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"It's My Life"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Someday I'll Be Saturday Night"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Wanted Dead or Alive"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"I'll Sleep When I'm Dead"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Have a Nice Day"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Keep the Faith"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Bad Medicine"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "@encore":"1",
               "song":[
                  {
                     "@name":"Always"
                  },
                  {
                     "@name":"Livin' on a Prayer"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "@encore":"2",
               "song":{
                  "@name":"These Days"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "url":"https://www.setlist.fm/setlist/bon-jovi/2017/allianz-parque-sao-paulo-brazil-23e278a7.html"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle for `object` or `string`. For last iteration you are getting string, so try like this

```
<?php
    $setlista="23e278a7";
    $url = "http://api.setlist.fm/rest/0.1/setlist/".$setlista.".json";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($obj->setlist->sets->set as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value->song as $key => $song) {
            echo ($count).". ";
            echo is_object($song) ? $song->{'@name'} : $song;
            echo "<br>\n";
            $count++;
        }
    }
?>
```

Live demo with your sample data : https://eval.in/875794